# Resources located twice when Spring Boot JAR resides in path with spaces

Tags: java, spring-boot

While transferring some "legacy" code into a Spring Boot application I noticed unusual behaviour when deploying the "fat jar" version of the code, relating to wildcard classpath scanning.

The legacy code uses Dozer mapping, configured by XML, with the mapping configurations distributed over several packages (they are kept close to the classes they are mapping). In order to locate these we use a factory bean, which uses quite permissive wildcard classpath scanning:

```
@Bean
public DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean dozerBeanMapperFactoryBean(
    @Value("classpath*:**/*_dozer_mapping.xml") Resource[] resources) { ... }
```

This works, and finds all of the required configuration files.  The Spring Boot application is compiled into a runnable "fat jar" using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Everything is fine until the runnable JAR is placed in a location (in Windows) with a Space in the path (for example in `C:\Program Files\MySoftware\myApplication.jar`).  When this happens, the parameter passed into the Bean method above contains some of the located configuration files *twice* (which Dozer doesn't like).

Debugging into the Spring Framework suggests that the issue is somewhere within `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver::findPathMatchingResources`.  The code in question is:

```
String rootDirPath = determineRootDir(locationPattern);
String subPattern = locationPattern.substring(rootDirPath.length());
Resource[] rootDirResources = getResources(rootDirPath);
```

If installed into a folder with spaces in the path, the `getResources` call returns an extra URL Resource, such as:

```
URL [jar:file:C:\Program Files\MySoftware\myApplication.jar!/]
```

And as a result the configuration files within that JAR are detected twice, and passed to (in this case) the `dozerBeanMapperFactoryBean` (which causes issues with duplicate definitions).

As a simple test, create a Spring Boot application such as this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApp {
  private Resource[] resources;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
  }

  public TestApp(@Value("classpath*:**/*.xml") Resource[] resources) {
    this.resources = resources;
  }
}
```

Add an XML file into the resources folder.  Compile as a single jar using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` with `<goal>repackage</goal>`.  When run as a JAR located in a path with spaces, the XML file is located twice.

Is there something we've missed here?  I would not expect that the wide wildcard would result in this behaviour.

We are using Spring Boot `2.3.1.RELEASE` in this instance.

Comment: try to replace 'classpath*:' with 'classpath:' , asterisk here means all classpathes, potential reason for your issue.

Comment: Yes, using `classpath*:` will expand the search out to include all classpaths, including allowing _no_ resources to be found. But I would still expect the result to be no different based on where the jar is located. As an aside, we don't get the issue if we include a root package (`classpath*:com/**/*.xml`), but that will exclude files stored in the root.

Comment: Story with spaces in path is actually long for Java, not sure if its possible to solve that easily. Could suggest to make manual resource filtering after injection.